# SQL Server : best practice for updating many rows at once with different IDs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I want to update many rows in a single command with different IDs. These IDs should be passed in the query like

```
Update table
Set Updated = 1
where ID is in 
(
     1
     2
     3
)
```

The further difficulty is that there are two primary key columns to check for. I don't want to update each row in its own command because its very slow because of the server roundtrips.

What is the best way to update a table like this?

Comment: What do you mean by two primary key columns? A table can only have one primary key (though it can be a composite).

Comment: Did you mean that your primary key is compound - is made of more than one field?  If so, than **the only option** is to update each record separately, you can do it the way ErikE suggested to cut on the round-trips.

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: The server is Microsoft SQL Server 2008 and yes I mean a combounded pk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the table to a derived table that contains a VALUES clause (SQL 2008) or a series of UNION ALL SELECTs.

```
UPDATE T
SET Col = 1
FROM dbo.Table T
INNER JOIN (
   VALUES
      (1, 3),
      (3, 5),
      (5, 7)
) X (ID1, ID2)
   ON T.ID1 = X.ID1
   AND T.ID2 = X.ID2
```

For SQL 2005 and earlier:

```
UPDATE T
SET Col = 1
FROM dbo.Table T
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 1, 3
   UNION ALL SELECT 3, 5
   UNION ALL SELECT 5, 7
) X (ID1, ID2)
   ON T.ID1 = X.ID1
   AND T.ID2 = X.ID2
```

Alternately, insert to a temp table and join to that. You could also create a stored procedure that accepts a parameter containing all the keys you need to join with. The parameter could be text (which you would split), xml, or a table-valued parameter.

If the amount of data is simply enormous then you might consider doing a bulk load of the keys from a text file into a table.

Comment: Or use a table variable, a temp table or table valued parameter.

Comment: I was getting to that but typing on my phone is so slow!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax was almost right. The following will execute as expected:

```
Update table
Set Updated = 1
where ID IN 
(
     1,
     2,
     3
)
```

If you need to match on multiple columns, you need to have a source of data that contains those columns - a temp table, a table variable or a table valued parameter can work. You would join your table on this source and run the update on it.

```
UPDATE table
SET Updated = 1
FROM table
  INNER JOIN otherTable
    ON table.Col1 = otherTable.Col1
    AND table.Col2 = otherTable.Col2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update based on a single primary key in a comma seperated list. 
So in your case:

```
update tblTable set updated = 1 where id in (1,2,3)
```

You can use an update where condition just as you would with a SELECT command. 
You didn't stipulate with version of SQL Server, but here is the SQL2k Books Online Link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662(v=sql.80).aspx

SQL Books Online is a good place to start for questions of this nature (i.e. command structure)

Comment: And the composite key issue?

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If your "selection" of records to update is defined in a programming language (eg you are writing the query in c# and then passing it to sql server) your simplest solution is to generate a series of where clauses like so:

```
OR (KeyColumn1 = @FilterValue1_1 AND KeyColumn2 = @FilterValue2_1)
OR (KeyColumn1 = @FilterValue1_2 AND KeyColumn2 = @FilterValue2_2)
```

If your selection comes directly from another query, embed it in the update statement like so:

```
UPDATE
    [TableToUpdate]
SET
    [ColumnToUpdate] = @NewValue
FROM
    [TableToUpdate]
    INNER JOIN [FilterTable]
        ON [FilterTable].[KeyColumn1] = [TableToUpdate].[KeyColumn1]
        AND [FilterTable].[KeyColumn2] = [TableToUpdate].[KeyColumn2]
WHERE
    [FilterTable].[ColumnToFilter] = @ValueToFilter
```

Or like this:

```
UPDATE
    [TableToUpdate]
SET
    [ColumnToUpdate] = @NewValue
FROM
    [TableToUpdate]
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            [FilterTable].[KeyColumn1],
            [FilterTable].[KeyColumn2]
        FROM
            [FilterTable]
        WHERE
            [FilterTable].[ColumnToFilter] = @ValueToFilter
    )
        AS [Filter]
        ON [Filter].[KeyColumn1] = [TableToUpdate].[KeyColumn1]
        AND [Filter].[KeyColumn2] = [TableToUpdate].[KeyColumn2]
```

Or even like this :)

```
;WITH [Filter] AS
(
    SELECT
        [FilterTable].[KeyColumn1],
        [FilterTable].[KeyColumn2]
    FROM
        [FilterTable]
    WHERE
        [FilterTable].[ColumnToFilter] = @ValueToFilter
)
UPDATE
    [TableToUpdate]
SET
    [ColumnToUpdate] = @NewValue
FROM
    [TableToUpdate]
    INNER JOIN [Filter]
        ON [Filter].[KeyColumn1] = [TableToUpdate].[KeyColumn1]
        AND [Filter].[KeyColumn2] = [TableToUpdate].[KeyColumn2]
```